# Automaticly setting default texts in select dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, selection

I have a very simple select dropdown with urls that direct users to respective pages

```
   <select>
         <option value="url1">title1 </option>
         <option value="url2">title2 </option>
         <option value="url3">title3 </option>
         .........
   </select>
```

I will have this drop down in all these (url1, url2, url3...) serving for navigation. Would it be possible to set the default text in the selection box based on my urls? Say if I am currently on url2, my default text in the selection box will be title2. I know manually you can just use

```
        <option selected="selected" value="url2">title2</option>
```

But is there a way I can use javascript to do because I have hundreds of pages? All the urls and titles are stored in an array that I can retrieve.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Please show a sample of your array then so that we could perhaps find a way to figure something out. Perhaps you could add another field in with the URL as the "display name" for the URL. Regardless, some more clarification and explanation of what you've done so far would help greatly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to match the url in the window location (such as `http://www.example.com/some/page.html`) with the URL to the page found in your dropdown:

```
var dropdown = document.getElementById( 'dropdown' );
for ( var i = 0; i < dropdown.childElementCount; ++i ) {
    if ( dropdown.children[i].value === document.location.href) {
        dropdown.selectedIndex = i;
        break;
    }
}
```

Where `'dropdown'` contains the ID of your `<select>` element. Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/RhZy6/

Comment: Personally like this one the best..even though all the other answers are great too! Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use this:

```
var path = decodeURIComponent(window.location.pathname.replace(/\/$/, ""));
$("option").each(function () {
    var url = $(this).val();
    if (path.substring(0, url.length) === url) {
        $(this).prop('selected', true);
    }
});
```

Path is the end of the URL. The next block of code loops through the option elements and looks to see if the option value matches the path, and if it does, sets the selected property to true.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the current URL using `document.URL` and on document ready you can use ,

```
$("#selectId option[value=" + document.URL + "]").prop('selected', true);
```

However `document.URL` contains full path , so you need to truncate the unnecessary part like http:// https:/ , if it is not present in `value` of select.

#### And , here is the [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sFqP6/)

P.S The Fiddle will work second time only. It is shwoing diffrent URL on first time. Gotta be a JSFiddle personal thing.

Answer (score 0):

Say you have

```
<form name="MyForm">
<select name="SelectBox1">
<option>One
<option>Two
<option>Three
</select>
```

.. etc .. rest of form/page ..

then in your javascript code ..

```
var el=document.forms.MyForm.SelectBox1;
el.selectedIndex=2; // sets option to "Three" in Select box, because first option is number 0, second =1, third = 2 etc
```

Or to set it to a value use a function like this .. pass in the Select field name and the value it should be

```
function setSelect(sFieldName, sValue) {
  var el=document.getElementsByName(sFieldName)[0] // returns array of all elements with that name so use [0] to get 1st one
  for (var i=0;i<el.options.length;
    if (el.options[i].value == sValue) { // if they match...
       el.selectedIndex=i; // then this should be the default
    }
}
```

call it usiong something like

```
setSelect("SelectBox1","http://ectetc")
```

Comment: I am a bit confused about the code you gave 'cause I am a newbie. Could you elaborate it a bit more?

Comment: the <form name="MyForm"> tag is just a declaration of the form containing the field. You could also access it with document.getElementsByName("SelectBox1") which returns an array of all elements with that name, or put id="Select1" in the Select box attributes and use document.getElementById("Select1")